# Timezone in iPhone is wrong for Tonga

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a user in Tonga (Wallis/Futuna & Tonga) for whom my app is not working correctly. Whatever I do, timezone in Tonga is not correctly calculated in iPhone.

All these following code return 12:

```
let tZone1: Double = Double(NSTimeZone.system.secondsFromGMT()) / 3600.0
let tZone2: Double = Double(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()) / 3600.0
let tZone3: Double = Double(NSTimeZone.default.secondsFromGMT() ) / 3600.0
let tZone4: Double = Double(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT(for: Date()) ) / 3600.0
```

And timezone abbreviation is "GMT+12"

```
let tZoneAbr = TimeZone.current.abbreviation()
```

though correct timezone for Tonga is GMT+13 (lat: -12.1333, lon: -175.3).

Is there a way that I can correctly calculate time-zone as +13? Or is that an OS limitation?

Comment: What Timezone do they have their device set to?  Wallis/Futuna is GMT+12 while Tonga is GMT+13.  They are different countries with different time zones.  If I set my device manually to each of those time zones I get the right answer.  If I set time zone to Nuku'alofa `TimeZone.autoUpdatingCurrent` is "Pacific/Tongatapu" with 46800 seconds from GMT.  Mata-Utu, on the other hand is "Pacifc/Wallis" and 43200

Comment: Thanks Paulw11. I set my computer's timezone to "Mata-Ulu- Wallis & Futura" and got +12 in iPhone simulator. Setting it to "Nuku'alofa - Tonga" resulted in +13. So it seems the user was traveling between two regions (he is ship captain) and his phone's timezone was not updating properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting scenario, but there's not much you can do about it.  The internal behavior of an automatic time zone setting feature on most devices is not something that you as a programmer have any control over.  In some cases there's a cell tower signal that can change the time zone, and in other cases the GPS coordinates are cross referenced to time zone using internal map data.  In neither case can you do anything about an incorrect setting other than to disable the automatic time zone feature and set the time zone manually.

Also, while time zones on land (and in surrounding territorial waters) are well defined, time zones at sea are not.  While one can guess that the captain might like to switch to the other time zone on a longitudinal line or by the international date line, the reality is that a captain of a ship or airplane can set their clock to any time zone they wish, at any point in the journey.  It's not uncommon to pick an arbitrary half-way point to switch the clocks, or to leave the ship's clock alone until arriving at the destination, depending on the length of the voyage.

The best advice I can give would to tell the user that the application will respond to time zone changes on the device and it's up to them to change the device's time zone at their own discretion.

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented a workaround for the problem as the result of my calculation using timezone was 1 day off. If I see very large error in calculated time (> 24 hour), I subtract 24 hours. This should fix the problem but I agree that this is really a corner case scenario that happens in plane or ship.